# How to add multiple host in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, connection

I am trying to run below script & it's working fine for one host but I want to add multiple host.

```
host=1.2.3.4
LOG_OK=/tmp/port-check-success.log
LOG_FAIL=/tmp/port-check-failed.log

for port in 80 443
do
if telnet -c $host $port </dev/null 2>&1 | grep -q Escape; then
  echo  "$port: Connected" >> $LOG_OK
else
  echo "$port : no connection" >> $LOG_FAIL
fi
done
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have a `for` loop for `host` in the same way that you are already doing for `port`, and nest one loop inside the other.  For example:

```
LOG_OK=/tmp/port-check-success.log
LOG_FAIL=/tmp/port-check-failed.log

for host in 1.2.3.4 5.6.7.8
do
    for port in 80 443
    do
        if telnet -c $host $port </dev/null 2>&1 | grep -q Escape; then
            echo "$host: $port: Connected" >> $LOG_OK
        else
            echo "$host: $port : no connection" >> $LOG_FAIL
        fi
    done
done
```

Comment: that broke the script, now its not ending keep on running.

Comment: @Vijaykhurava In what situation do you want it to end, that it is not currently doing?

Comment: my earlier script immediately printing the results of Telent in that file whether its fail or pass but now its taking so much time & no file is being create neither fail or pass

Comment: @Vijaykhurava Probably one of the hosts that you are trying to contact is not responding.  Instead of just `telnet ...`, you could try for example `timeout 10 telnet ...` to wait for up to 10 seconds.

Comment: @Vijaykhurava Glad it worked. (I won't edit the answer to include `timeout`, because it does not relate directly to the question.)

Comment: Sure thing no problem !